# Problem in bibtex when using authordate1 bibliography style

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib

I need to use the `authordate1` style in my thesis. When I compile, it always shows a lot of errors from bibtex.

My bibtex file is:

```
@Book{ Card:1983:PHI:578027,
    author = "Stuart K. Card and Allen Newell and Thomas P. Moran",
    title = "The Psychology of Human-Computer Interaction",
    year = "1983",
    isbn = "0898592437",
    publisher = "L. Erlbaum Associates Inc.",
    address = "Hillsdale, NJ, USA"
}
```

---

My tex file is

```
\documentclass[spanish,a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

%\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}

\begin{document}
Lista de referencias

\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{authordate1}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

---

When I compile without `\usepackage[square,sort]{natbib}`, I always get erros from bibtex (one from each reference), and I have to pulse the "intro" key for each one.

```
/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/latin1.def)) (./listareferencias.aux)
(./listareferencias.bbl [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
[2]
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citename 
                              {Card {\em et~al.\ }\relax , }1983
l.4   }1983]{Card:1983:PHI:578027}
```

And my bibliography looks:

```
[Card et al. , 1983] Card, Stuart K., Newell, Allen, & Moran, Thomas P. 1983.
The Psychology of Human-Computer Interaction. Hillsdale, NJ, USA: L. Erl-
baum Associates Inc.
```

However, if I use `natbib`, I get no errors, but my bibliography has no brackets:

```
Card, Stuart K., Newell, Allen, & Moran, Thomas P. 1983. The Psychology
of Human-Computer Interaction. Hillsdale, NJ, USA: L. Erlbaum Associates
Inc.
```

Thanks in advance, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 7):

The bibtex style requires a matching latex package so you need to add

```
\usepackage{authordate1-4}
```

to your preamble

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/authordate/authordate1-4.sty

Comment: Thanks David, but it doesn't work. The bibliography text has no square brackets

Comment: That's not "not working" That's what the style does, it has `\def\@biblabel#1{}` which removes the label from the bibliography.  Could of course redefine it back so the label is there, but simpler would be to use a bibliography style that is closer to what you need. Perhaps you want no `\usepackage` but just add `\let\citename\relax`